# Excel: Dynamic INDIRECT when copying cell formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula

```
=INDIRECT("'"&$A$1&"'!"&"D3")
```

in A1 I have the name of another sheet and this correctly goes to that sheet, cell D3 and return the value. Now I'd like to drag this formula on the cell below and be automatically updated to

```
=INDIRECT("'"&$A$1&"'!"&"E3")
```

then drag below again and have

```
=INDIRECT("'"&$A$1&"'!"&"F3")
```

and so on...

is it possible or I have to manually change the cell? Is there another way?

thanks

Comment: You want to drag down and change the column reference?

Comment: yes, excatly! thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the column reference as the formula is dragged down, use ADDRESS() which returns a string:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & $A$1 & "'!"&ADDRESS(3,ROW(4:4)))
```

The ROW() will be Dynamic and refer first to the 4th Column, or "D" and as it is dragged down it will refer to the 5th then the 6th and so forth.

Comment: thanks, but what if I have a range? =INDIRECT("'"&$A$1&"'!"&"D3:EI3"). I tried the following but I get an error: =INDIRECT("'" & $A$1 & "'!"&ADDRESS(3,ROW(4:4))&":"&ADDRESS(3,ROW(40:40)))

Comment: Then you would concatenate the two addresses: `=INDIRECT("'" & $A$1 & "'!"&ADDRESS(3,ROW(4:4)) & ":" & ADDRESS(13,ROW(5:5)))` remember Indirect turns a string into a viable address.  So as long as the string creates an address it will work. @kiwi1342

Comment: You've put one of the brackets to the wrong place. `=INDIRECT("'"&$A$1&"'!"&ADDRESS(3,ROW(4:4))&":"&ADDRESS(3,ROW(40:40)))`